# TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation with stack 5 version.

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Movie" component={Movie} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
     )
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Movie', { title: item.title, img: item.img, id: item.imdbID }) }}>
      // code omitted               
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

I clicked movie item to movie details but I am getting error message and it says:

```
TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function
```

**Movie.js**

```
   componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovieDetails(this.props.navigation.getParam('id', 'n/a')) 
    }

    getMovieDetails = async (id) => {
         const results = await fetchById(id)
         this.setState({ info: results })
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props
        const title = navigation.getParam('title', 'N/A');
        const img = navigation.getParam('img', 'https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180216/kee/kisspng-photographic-film-reel-clip-art-movie-film-5a8677562304e0.0541516415187618141435.jpg');
}
```

[image]

Could you please help me with this issue?
I am waiting for your response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make a snack with this issue on expo? if yes share it with me and I will fix it.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar 
https://snack.expo.io/@adnan.salah84/04697d
Note: Do not use web. Try android or IOS
Thanks

Comment: Here is the solution to your problem in this snack, Also if it works, please mark my question as accepted.
https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/home_movie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snack with the solution that you required, I have made a few changes in your code and your error is fixed now in this snack.
`You were trying to access getParams function but that wasn't available inside the navigation object` so instead of `getting params with getParams function I directly get these params from this.pros.navigation.route.params`

https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/home_movie

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in `react-native` while passing `props` with navigation. You could try this approach to see if it works.

```
//Home.js

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate({'Movie', { title: item.title, img: item.img, id: item.imdbID }}) }}>
```

And in the `Movie.js` you can access the props like this.

```
//Movie.js
componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovieDetails(this.props.route.params) 
    }
```

*Update:*

```
 //Home.js
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Movie', { title: item.title, img: item.img, id: item.imdbID }) }}>
      // code omitted               
      </TouchableHighlight>
```

```
    //Movie.js
    componentDidMount(){
          const navObject = this.props.navigation.state.params 
          console.log(navObject )
    }
```

Comment: Same issue. 
Please see my screenshot as I updated my first post!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you check it out @AdnanSalahuddin

Comment: After update console.log. It is nothing. I got error about navigation.getParam. It says not function.
I think there is something problem with 
`const { navigation } = this.props
const title = navigation.getParam('title', 'N/A');`

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? @AdnanSalahuddin

Comment: Nope. I am sharing the snack with you if you are comfortable
https://snack.expo.io/@adnan.salah84/04697d

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
    do:{
      name: props.route.params.name,
      color: props.route.params.color
    }
};
```